# Viewing days left to events in a Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I use Google Calendar for keeping track of deadline dates for various projects. What I'd really like is a view where I can see the number of days left until each deadline in my "Deadlines" calendar.

Is there any existing solution that will give me this type of view of my data? It doesn't have to be built in to Google Calendar itself, it could just take as input a (iCAL|XML) link to the calendar.

(Ideally, it would be "work days" left, so it would not count weekends. Even better would be for it to not count "holidays" as specified in a different calendar. But both of these are enhancements).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Calendar: show remaining (countdown) time to events?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/google-calendar-show-remaining-countdown-time-to-events)