# Show remaining (countdown) time to events?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

How can I show the remaining time to events in their title in Google Calendar?

For example: Meeting with Kate (`1day 1h 30m left`)

Comment: I don't think there is any standard way or already builtin solution. You should try building a [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

There's no standard way to do this. There is however, a Labs feature which shows time to the next event on the sidebar. But again not on the title.

[image: Labs setting]

[image]